# webbrowser control acts different than IE c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, caching, cookies, webbrowser-control

So I've got my WebBrowser application which is constantly accessing website to do some stuff.. 
The problem is at some point this website is starting to be unavailable to my WebBrowser but I can still access it from IE.
It is related to some punishment from this website's "security algorithms?", but I wonder why I can access it with IE while my WebBrowser is "banned"? I tried to clear cache, cookies(programatically), change my IP by HideMyAss or TunnelBear but no results. I've also forced my WebBrowser to use the latest IE version. Results are I can't visit this website for some time via my webbrowser, but I can via IE..

```
        int BrowserVer, RegVal;

        using (WebBrowser Wb = new WebBrowser())
            BrowserVer = Wb.Version.Major;

        // set the appropriate IE version
        if (BrowserVer >= 11)
            RegVal = 11001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 10)
            RegVal = 10001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 9)
            RegVal = 9999;
        else if (BrowserVer == 8)
            RegVal = 8888;
        else
            RegVal = 7000;

        // set the actual key
        using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
            if (Key.GetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe") == null)
                Key.SetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe", RegVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

How this website recognizes my webbrowser control? Is it anything more that I can clear/dispose to be not recognized?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by: "_The problem is at some point this website is starting to be unavailable to my WebBrowser but I can still access it from IE_"

Comment: What is the error message that your web browser control tells you?

Comment: It is not error, it's just website shows some text like "Unauthorized access..". Seems like if you enter that page multiple times in a specified time you will be "timeouted" or "banned" for like 3-4 hours.This is not error, I'm just wondering what can I do to be not recognized as a browser that entered there like many times in last hour.

https://imgur.com/a/Yby9Da2

Answer (score 1):

> How this website recognizes my webbrowser control? Is it anything more
>   that I can clear/dispose to be not recognized?

You could check the HTTP request when using IE and browser control access the website, and compare the request URL to check whether it append a query string to the URL.

Besides, you could also refer to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/737b54ee-6478-4354-8a51-bcf2e84256a3/web-page-detect-if-opened-from-webbrowser-control?forum=winforms) and check whether it's using property to detect if web page opened from WebBrowser control.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I think changing user-agent will do the trick, however I haven't checked it yet.